# How to find the intersection points of 2 cylinders in terms of r, R, t, a?

Tags: calculus, matrices, trigonometry

The first equation describes a cylinder rotated on the $y$ axis by the angle $t$:

$$x^2\cos^2(t)+z^2\sin^2(t)-2xz \cos(t)\sin(t)+y^2=r^2$$

The second equation:

$$x^2+y^2=R^2$$ where $R \neq r$.

The question is: How do we find the intersection points of the 2 cylinders in terms of $r, R, t, a$, like

$(x, y, z)= \text{ "something in terms of" } 
(t,r,R,a)$

**a** is the angle in the parametrization format for **x**, and **t** is the angle of cylinder.

$$x=r*cos(a).$$

They should give $2$ ellipses.

[image: Intersection of cylinders]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to substitute $x=R\sin\beta$, $y=R\cos\beta$ into your top equation, which takes care of the restriction on $x$ and $y$. That gives you a quadratic in $z$
$$
z^2\sin^2t-2z\sin\beta\cos t\sin t+R^2(\sin^2\beta\cos^2t+\cos^2\beta)-r^2
$$
You can solve that with the quadratic formula, then you can substitute back in $x$ and $y$ if you need to.

Answer (score -1):

Here the answer for the intersection equation for the **z** point:

**eq.1**
(Describes a cylinder rotated on the y axis by the angle t).

$$x^2\cos^2(t)+z^2\sin^2(t)-2xz \cos(t)\sin(t)+y^2=r^2$$

**eq.2**

$$x^2+y^2=R^2$$

where $R \neq r$.

**intersection with eq. 1 & 2.**
(using parametrization).

substituting $$y^2=R^2-X^2$$ from **eq.1** into **eq.2** and parametrizing **x** as:

$$r*cos(t)$$
$$R*cos(t)$$

**Rearranging we get:**

$$z(-z*sin(t)+2(r*cos(a))*cos(t)sin(t))=R^2-r^2-(R*cos(a))^2+(r*cos(a))^2*cos^2(t)$$

**Solving for z we get:**

there are **z**, **z1** because the intersection has two different ellipses.**quadratic in z**

$$z = csc(t) (sqrt(sin(t) (r^2 (-cos^2(a)) cos^2(t) + r^2 cos^2(a) sin(t) cos^2(t) + R^2 cos^2(a) + r^2 - R^2)) + r cos(a) sin(t) cos(t))$$

**end**

$$z1 = csc(t) (r cos(a) sin(t) cos(t) - sqrt(sin(t) (r^2 (-cos^2(a)) cos^2(t) + r^2 cos^2(a) sin(t) cos^2(t) + R^2 cos^2(a) + r^2 - R^2)))$$

**Variables used to graph the point z:**

r= First cylinder radius.

R= Second cylinder radius.

t --> 0 to 2*pi

**EXAMPLE:**

Test for **z** point at **a**= 45 deg, (**t** goes from **0** to **2*pi**):

R=r=1

$$z = csc(45) (1 cos(a) sin(45) cos(45) - sqrt(sin(45) (1^2 (-cos^2(a)) cos^2(45) + 1^2 cos^2(a) sin(45) cos^2(45) + 1^2 cos^2(a) + 1^2 - 1^2)))$$

$$z1 = csc(45) (sqrt(sin(45) (1^2 (-cos^2(a)) cos^2(45) + 1^2 cos^2(a) sin(45) cos^2(45) + 1^2 cos^2(a) + 1^2 - 1^2)) + 1 cos(a) sin(45) cos(45))$$

**Plot of z & z1 using wolframalpha**

[image]